# How to validate the ContextItem in xquery

Tags: xquery, saxon

My XSLT is primitive, my XQuery almost non existent, this should be trivial, so I wont post a whole example.

I have an XQuery, that I'm compiling and executing via the dotnet saxon9ee-api

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "MessingAbout.xsd";

for $v in (validate { doc("MessingAbout.xml") })/element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)
return <OUTPUT>{$v/@colour}</OUTPUT>
```

which works very nicely.

I want to use the "ContextItem" though, so I can query different XMLS, and I've got this to work, by setting the ContextItem in the XQueryEvaluator to a document.

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "MessingAbout.xsd";

for $v in /SQUARE
return <OUTPUT>{$v/@colour}</OUTPUT>
```

but I'd like to validate the contextItem and then use that do use things like element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)...but how do you do this?

Comment: As for the context item itself, you can declare it with a type if you want e.g. `declare context item as document-node(element(foo, bar)) external;`. But I am not sure your question is about that issue or about the proper use of the Saxon API to use schema-aware XQuery with a validated input document or some XQuery syntax to validate some nodes.

Comment: Assuming you created the context item you set with ContextItem with validation enabled, the expression would just be `for $v in /element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)` instead of `for $v in (validate { doc("MessingAbout.xml") })/element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to do, but given "MessingAbout.xsd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="FILLEDSQUARETYPE">
    <xs:attribute name="colour" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="SQUARE" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and "MessingAbout.xml":

```
<SQUARE colour="red"/>
```

your first query produces `<OUTPUT colour="red"/>`, which I assume is what you expect. To use the context item in the second query, I rewrote it as:

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "MessingAbout.xsd";

for $v in (validate { . })/element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)
return <OUTPUT>{$v/@colour}</OUTPUT>
```

and passed the source document on the command line: `-q:test2.xq -s:MessingAbout.xml`.

That gives me the same result as the first query. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: thats the one...I knew I'd seen "." somewhere, but I was trying "doc(.)" which obviously gave me an error, and couldnt find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the approaches suggested by Martin and Norm, you have the option of doing the validation in the calling application, e.g. Java or C#. Build the document using a s9api DocumentBuilder with validation options set, and then pass the resulting typed XdmNode as the context item when running the query. This approach is preferable if you want to do more with the validated document than just running one query. But if you do it this way, it's useful for the query to assert that it's expecting a validated document, which you can do with a "declare context-item" in the query prolog.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look at that, it was the XQuery syntax I was struggling with.